# API jetstream laravel 8x not works in GET

Tags: laravel, api, get, token

i created this route in routes/api:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/', function (Request $request) {
return response('MJ-12');});
```

I created the token with jetstream with Read permission

when i go to do the GET call with Insomnia with the following parameters:

```
GET: http://laravel.test/api
Content-Type:application/json
Accept:application/json
Authorization:Bearer 37b3mWZ9BHc....LRZwbTnYBKtcQss
```

I don't get the MJ-12 response but the following 404:

```
{
  "message": "No query results for model [App\\Models\\Poll] api",
  "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
  "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
  "line": 364,
  "trace": [
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
      "line": 313,
      "function": "prepareException",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 51,
      "function": "render",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 172,
      "function": "handleException",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php",
      "line": 44,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php",
      "line": 77,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
      "line": 49,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/AuthenticateSession.php",
      "line": 39,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\AuthenticateSession",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
      "line": 121,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
      "line": 63,
      "function": "handleStatefulRequest",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
      "line": 37,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php",
      "line": 67,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 103,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 693,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 668,
      "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 634,
      "function": "runRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 623,
      "function": "dispatchToRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
      "line": 166,
      "function": "dispatch",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 128,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
      "line": 21,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
      "line": 21,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
      "line": 27,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
      "line": 87,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php",
      "line": 37,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
      "line": 57,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 103,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
      "line": 141,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
      "line": 110,
      "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/.../laravel/public/index.php",
      "line": 52,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/Users/gianmarx/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php",
      "line": 191,
      "function": "require"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work it seems to me a simple function and I can't identify the conflict

Comment: try removing the middleware to check if you still get the same error.

Comment: i changed the routes/api as follows:   Route::get('/', function () {
    return response('MJ-12');
}); but it gives me the usual 404 error ...

Comment: So it is not related to Jetstream. Try returning just a string like `return "whatever";`

Comment: same result 404 ...

Comment: show your routes, you probably have a route that is catching that URI

Comment: Then surely, the issue is in your routing. List the routes by running `php artisan route:list` and see if you can find your route there.

Comment: yes and present. it seems to me more a problem of conflict. because I tried to install everything on another laravel folder and it works. only in this project I cannot understand the conflict

Comment: i just found that if i put the following route:

    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/s', function (Request $request) {
        return response('MJ-12');
    });

and I do the GET: http://poll-example.test/api/s with Insomnia it works.
while if I put the following route with the root it doesn't work INCOMPARABLE:

    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/', function (Request $request) {
        return response('MJ-12');
    });

and when I do the GET: http://poll-example.test/api/

gives me the usual error as the route did not exist